# Why does does this implicit use of ToString() not cause an exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a trivial example with which to ask this question.

The following code compiles and runs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string bigString, littleString;
    littleString = null;
    bigString = "word " + littleString + " word";
}
```

This code compiles but throws a runtime NullReference exception.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string bigString, littleString;
    littleString = null;
    bigString = "word " + littleString.ToString() + " word";
}
```

Why does the first code not throw a similar exception? I would have thought that in order to concatenate it to the other strings that there would be an implicit use of ToString(), at which point it would run into the same fundamental problem as the second piece of code.

Comment: Because internally [`String.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft(v=vs.110).aspx) is used which handles that case: _"String.Empty is used in place of any null argument"_

Comment: Why do you think the first example involves `ToString` at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first snippet doesn't call `ToString` at all.  It calls `string.Concat(string, string)` which in its implementation, handles `null` values as if they were empty strings.  It doesn't need to call `ToString` to convert that argument to a `string` (whether it's `null` or not) because *it is already a `string`*.  (If it *weren't* a `string`, then it *would* need to call `ToString` on it, but it would only do so if it is not `null`).

Answer (score 3):

This is how `String.Concat` works. The operator `+` *(for string values)* uses `string.Concat` which substitutes `null` string to empty string. Thus there is no implicit call to `ToString` in string concatenation for null values.

In your second code snippet you are explicitly calling `ToString` on a null value, thus the exception.

[How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

> In string concatenation operations, the C# compiler treats a null
>   string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value
>   of the original null string.

[7.7.4 Addition operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375(VS.71).aspx)

> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string.
>
> **If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted.** Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its
>   string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method
>   inherited from type object.

Answer (score 1):

In string concatenation operations, the C# compiler treats a null string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value of the original null string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx